# GoogleMap object returns null after executing the following code

Tags: java, android

Here is the XML file for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the Android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maptest2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.maptest2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.maptest2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maptest2.MapTest2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MyKey" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the piece of code:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            googleMap = mapFrag.getMap();
```

I even tried it with "MapFragment" instead of "SupportMapFragment" with no luck same error.

I have been researching for days. Could someone please assist me with this. Thanks

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html. With over 97% of devices now running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or newer platform versions, **we’re dropping support for Froyo from this release of the Google Play services SDK in order to make it possible to offer more powerful APIs in the future. That means you will not be able to utilize these new APIs on devices running Android 2.2 (Froyo). Google map is part of google play services**.

Comment: So change your min sdk to api level 10 and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMap%28%29), the `GoogleMap` object will become available after the `SupportMapFragment`'s `onCreateView()` has been called, so a better idea will be to call `getMap()` in your `Activity`'s `onResume()`.